# $ABCD$, $P$ is any interior point, $PA=24, PB=32, PC=28, PD=45$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

could anyone tell me how to solve it?

I have a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$, $P$ is any interior point, $PA=24, PB=32, PC=28, PD=45$ cm, I need to know the perimeter of $ABCD$. Thanks for helping.

Area of the $ABCD$ was given $2002$ sq unit

Comment: are you sure that there is enough information to determine the perimeter?

Comment: 1. You've created a new (and unnecessary) tag and used only that tag on your question. 2. The question is generally not typed into the title bar. How come you have so much rep and still don't know such basic rules of the site.

Comment: question editeddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Comment: if you edit a question after it was answered by two users, don' you think you need to include that information in the body of the problem, not in the comments? it makes the answers look weird.

Answer (score 2):

$AC \le AP + PC = 24 + 28 = 52$ and $BD \le BP + PD=32+45 = 77$

adding $AB + BC < AC \le 52, BC + CD < BD \le 77,CD + DA < CA \le 52$ and
$DA + AB < DB \le 77$

we find that the perimeter is bounded above by $129.$

writing $AB = a, BC = b, Cd = c, DA = d,$ we have $$a + b + c + d \le 129, ac+bd \le 52*77=4004$$

i am stuck and not sure if the ptolemy inequality helps.

---

edit after question was edited:

with the area of the quadrilateral being $2002$ which is twice of what the ptolemy bound, you can see that the diagonals are collinear and orthogonal to each other.
so the perimeter is $$perimeter = \sqrt{24^2 + 32^2} + \sqrt{32^2 +28^2} + \sqrt{28^2 + 45^2 } + \sqrt{45^2 + 24^2}$$

ptolemy inequality sure helped. but an even easier method is pointed out by user orangekid in the comments below.

Comment: question editeddddddddddddddddd

Comment: @abel: The area of a quadrilateral is $1/2\  AD \cdot BC \cdot \sin \phi \le 1/2\  AD \cdot BC$.

Comment: @abel: So you  have done it, you got bounds on the diagonals and so $2002$ is the largest possible area.

Comment: @orangeskid, yes. when you say that it makes sense. i did not see before. it is the ptolemy that helped me see.

Comment: @abel: I mindlessly set up a maximization problem and got the angles $\pi/2$ and largest value $2002$, and that caught my attention. Indeed, for every lengths $PA$,$\ldots$ given, the largest area is when $P$ is the intersection of perpendicular diagonals. Yes, it's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

There is insufficient information to find the perimeter.

Draw point P and make 4 line segments from it, of given lengths. There is no way of finding the angles between them, and there are many cases that give a convex quadrilateral.